# Destroying activity when App looses focus

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have an Android application and I faced a weird problem. I have an activity and in the onStop() method I call finish() like so:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    finish();
}
```

The problem is that when I close the activity by pressing the round button in the navigation bar and then reopen the app from the recent apps tab in the navgiation bar then the activity is just recreated. That means the onCreate() method is called. What I would like instead is that the MainActivity is opened.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's because your activity is on top of the task manager. BTW it's an antipattern to finish activity in onStop() method. Can't you find another way maybe?

Comment: That is the intended behavior. Please make it clear in your question - "What is the purpose of calling `finish()` in `onStop()`?"

Comment: @GV_FiQst Is there another solution to achieve my goal? That means that when the application looses focus and then gains focus again that then the MainActivity is opened. Should I start MainActivity in onStop()?

Comment: please give us more details about the problem to look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you want by adding

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

to the `<activity>` declaration in your manifest.

In that case you don't need to add the all to `finish()` in `onStop()`.

I'm assuming your app has only one `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have set this flag to my activity but it does not change the behavior. My app does have a lot of activities, not only this one. Perhaps I was a bit unclear. My app has a main activity and also other activies. When the user opens one specific activity and then switches to another app and then back to the app, then I don't want that this activity is shown anymore, but instead the main activity.

Comment: Is this special `Activity` launched by `MainActivity`? Or can there be other activites in the stack between the `MainActivity` and this special `Activity`?

Comment: This special activity can be launched by the MainActivity but there are also cases where other activities can be in-between.

Comment: Perhaps instead of switching from this special activity to the MainActivity also the whole stack trace could be wiped when this special activity is paused.

Comment: If you set `noHistory="true"` then that `Activity` should go away whenever the user leaves it. It shouldn't get recreated in any case. Please make that change, add your manifest to your question and check if that helps. If not, please explain exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: It sounds like your application architecture needs some work. How is the user supposed to leave this special `Activity`? Doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: What finally worked now is to add android:excludeFromRecents="true"

Comment: Did you add `excludeFromRecents` to `MainActivity`? or to your special `Activity`? In any case, if you exclude the task from the list of recent tasks the user won't be able to leave your app and return to it, no matter what `Activity` it is currently in. If that's what you are after.

Comment: I have added it to the special Activity.

Comment: This makes no sense. Please add your manifest to your question. Normally `excludeFromRecents` is only applicable to the root `Activity` in a task and if `MainActivity` starts your special `Activity` it won't be the root `Activity` in the task.